# "bitsperlong.h" : trouble cross-building Perf for ARM (Android)

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, arm, perf

I am attempting to build Perf for Android, cross-built for the ARM architecture from an x86_64 Ubuntu system (12.04).  I am following the directions that come with the Linux kernel, at ./tools/perf/Documentation/android.txt.  I have attempted both the NDK-based build, and the AOSP-derived-sysroot methods, documented in that same text file.  However, I prefer the AOSP-derived-sysroot method.

This was sync of AOSP's 4.3_r3.1 tag, with kernel 3.10.17 added, and an appropriate .config file generated.  (Cross-built kernel was built prior to cross-build Perf attempt below.)

Building Perf for the host platform works fine.  But cross-building for ARM fails with the following error:

```
$ cd ~/work/aosp
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch
$ cd ${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/ndk
$ ./build/tools/build-ndk-sysroot.sh --abi=arm
$ export NDK_SYSROOT=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/ndk/build/platforms/android-3/arch-arm
$ export NDK_TOOLCHAIN=${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN}/arm-linux-androideabi-
$ cd ${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/kernel/tools/perf
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${NDK_TOOLCHAIN} CFLAGS="--sysroot=${NDK_SYSROOT}"
...
    CC perf.o
In file included from /home/rbissell/work/aosp/kernel/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/posix_types.h:35:0,
                 from /home/rbissell/work/aosp/kernel/include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:35,
                 from /home/rbissell/work/aosp/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include-fixed/sys/types.h:46,
                 from /home/rbissell/work/aosp/ndk/build/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/unistd.h:33,
                 from util/util.h:44,
                 from builtin.h:4,
                 from perf.c:9:
/home/rbissell/work/aosp/kernel/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h:4:29: fatal error: asm/bitsperlong.h: No such file or directory
```

There are numerous hits from Google on the topic of a missing 'bitsperlong.h' file, some of them even [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806353/cross-compiling-of-kernel-module-for-arm-architecture).  For the most part, those questions & answers fall into one of the following categories:

- Someone trying to build a kernel module (I am not)
- Someone who isn't cross-building, and just needs to install host kernel headers (I do not)

The only solution offered at the SO link I provided above is to edit Perf's source file to include `<asm-generic/bitsperlong.h>` instead of `<asm/bitsperlong.h>`... another variant I've seen is to create a symbolic link in the latter directory to the former.

Neither of those solutions seem kosher to me, and in any case just lead to other compilation errors, such as:

```
$ ln -s /home/rbissell/work/aosp/kernel/include/asm-generic /home/rbissell/work/aosp/kernel/include/asm
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${NDK_TOOLCHAIN} CFLAGS="--sysroot=${NDK_SYSROOT}"
...
    CC perf.o
In file included from /home/rbissell/work/aosp/ndk/build/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/unistd.h:33:0,
                 from util/util.h:44,
                 from builtin.h:4,
                 from perf.c:9:
/home/rbissell/work/aosp/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/include-fixed
/sys/types.h:73:1: error: unknown type name '__kernel_nlink_t'
```

At first I thought this problem might have been caused by not cross-building the kernel itself within that same source tree prior to building Perf (as, perhaps the kernel build sets up some $ARCH-appropriate symlinks, or something,) but after doing so, I still had this same problem.

**UPDATE:** In case it helps, this was how I cross-built my kernel:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/rbissell/work/aosp/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-
```

Comment: I think you do need to cross-build the kernel first (at least partially; similar to the situation when building a kernel module).  Did you specify the same `ARCH=arm` and `O=...` both when you cross-built the kernel and when you did the perf make?

Comment: The same `ARCH=arm`, yes.  There was no `O=...` on my command-lines (not sure if that was a typo on your part, or not.)  I will add my kernel-building command to my question, above.

Comment: Ryan, did you ever have any luck with this?  I am hitting the exact same problem.  Copy pasting the contents of bitsperlong.h into the .h including it will only get to the next problem of missing __kernel_nlink_t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at external/linux-tools-perf/

Comment: that's relatively old and not maintained and this is more of a comment.

Comment: Yes.  I have a professional need to build Perf for Android, for a kernel considerably newer than the 2 year-old 3.0.8 kernel that external/linux-tools-perf is based upon.  What's more, the documentation for linux 3.10 makes it clear that building Perf for Android is now supported officially.

Comment: This question is old and now moot... so even though this wasn't the appropriate answer for my needs at the time, it is likely the best answer for the average need.  So I am accepting it now.