# Cross compile module with arm-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I have a video module and I am compiling with `arm-eabi-gcc` cross compiler. I used following command to compile
`$ arm-eabi-gcc -O2 -DMODULE -D__KERNEL__ -W -Wall -isystem /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include panel-xxxxxxx.c`.

I got the following error

```
 In file included from /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build/include/linux/types.h:5:0,
             from /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build/include/linux/list.h:4,
             from /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build/include/linux/module.h:9,
             from panel-gis317.c:17:
/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h:4:23: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

And after searching on google, I found that I need to specify hardware architecture but I could not find the right usage to use `arch` with `gcc`on the command line.

Can anyone please suggest me the what flags can I use to cross-compile a give `.c`file(module) on the command line without using `Makefile`

Note: I am doing this to do `insmod` of `.ko` module on the hardware for test purpose.

BTW with the help of `.o` file, can we know which `cross-compiler` is used to compile the `.c file`

Comment: `-02` should be `-O2`

Comment: I am confused with the `uname -r` part in your compiler command line. That evaluates to the host's kernel release and not to the target's - Looks wrong to me. You need the target's kernel include files on the host and include those.

Answer (score 2):

With the linux kernel architecture specific includes are in arch//include. Though it will probably not ensure correct compilation just setting that...

But try adding /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/arch/arm/include to your include path.

Here's a simple guide for building your own kernel and modules for a Pi2 on your PC:
http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/Compiling-a-kernel-module-for-the-raspberry-pi-2

They use the makefile approach.

Answer (score 1):

The following link will help you 
[Cross-compiling of kernel module for ARM architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806353/cross-compiling-of-kernel-module-for-arm-architecture)

This has an example of the make file approach also.
As a side note if you want to have an Idea about the importance the "asm/types.h" in Linux you can have a look here to see what all functions use this .  http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html

For knowing more about your out (.o) file use the command "file"

"file  outputfilename.o" If you are cross compiling the file correctly and you are using a 64 bit system as host and your target is 32 bit you can verify it here. Your compiled output will be 32bit in proper working  case .

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to change in how you build an out-of-core kernel module.

First, use the kernel Makefile rather than invoking the compiler directly, in order to get all the necessary CFLAGS.

Second, specify CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- because other binutils are needed in the build.

Run the following command from the directory containing your module source code and Makefile:

```
$ make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -C <path_to_kernel_src> M=$PWD
```

The Makefile for a module consisting of a single source file would contain the following line:

```
obj-m := panel-xxxxxxx.o
```

The kernel kbuild Makefile rules would take care of generating a modinfo source file, and compiling and linking those into a .ko module binary.

See [Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) for more details.