# Cross-compile a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I have some errors when I try to cross-compile a kernel module ARM :

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/build M=/home/nari/Bureau modules
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic »
  CC [M]  /home/nari/Bureau/hello.o
In file included from include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h:10:0,
                 from ./arch/arm/include/asm/types.h:4,
                 from include/uapi/linux/types.h:4,
                 from include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from include/linux/list.h:4,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/nari/Bureau/hello.c:1:
include/uapi/asm-generic/int-ll64.h:11:29: fatal error: asm/bitsperlong.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:264 : la recette pour la cible « /home/nari/Bureau/hello.o » a échouée
make[2]: *** [/home/nari/Bureau/hello.o] Erreur 1
Makefile:1420 : la recette pour la cible « _module_/home/nari/Bureau » a échouée
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/nari/Bureau] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic »
Makefile:4 : la recette pour la cible « all » a échouée
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

This is my makefile :

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: I think this answer your question:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806353/cross-compiling-of-kernel-module-for-arm-architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806353/cross-compiling-of-kernel-module-for-arm-architecture)

Comment: Thank you but I've already tried this solution. I took the same makefile :

Comment: Thank you but I've already tried this solution. I took the same makefile. I only changed this line : KERNELDIR ?= Bureau/u-boot-2016.07/kernel but he doesn't even find it :make[1]: *** SUBDIRS=/home/nari/Bureau : no such file or directory ..

Comment: is KERNELDIR ?= Bureau/u-boot-2016.07/kernel a relative parh? try setting the full path

Comment: yes. It doesn't work. It recognize the path only when I use the path instead of ${KERNEL_SOURCE}.  but when i try make i have other errors like :

Comment: WARNING: Symbol version dump /home/nari/Bureau/u-boot-2016.07/kernel/kernel/Module.symvers is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions. CC [M]  /home/nari/Bureau/hello.o
gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-mabi=aapcs-linux’
gcc: note: valid arguments to ‘-mabi=’ are: ms sysv
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mlittle-endian’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-thumb-interwork’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’